# from mysql to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Looking for a simple solution here, I have looked around but nothing seems to give me a simple solution. I want to get data FROM my mysql database and then into my javascript variables.

These two var items in my `.js` file named `test.js` and this file is called into my `.html` file.

```
var tag_name = 'example';
var client_id = '123456789';
```

In a `.php` file called `call.php` I use this method (PDO) to get the required data from `MySQL`:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data WHERE id=1');
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$tag_name = $row['tag_name']; 
$client_id = $row['client_id'];
}
```

I want to try and achieve something along the lines of this in the `.js` file `test.js` - this obviously wont work but hopefully sheds some light on what I am trying to achieve:

```
var tag_name = '<?php echo $tag_name ?>';
var client_id = '<?php echo $client_id ?>';
```

Can I do this using an `Ajax` method? In my research I read that I need to use `JSON`? If the question has been asked before, please direct me to a post that is not just someone dumping 50+ lines of code.

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

The javascript part:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'call.php',
   dataType: 'json'
}).done(
   function(data){
     var tag_name = data[0];
     var client_id = data[1];
   }
);
```

The `call.php` file:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM data WHERE id=1');
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$tag_name = $row['tag_name']; 
$client_id = $row['client_id'];
}
echo json_encode(array($tag_name,$client_id));
```

Comment: Thanks, this will be the best option, however face some issues. Would `function(data)` be causing any form on conflict? I have more then just those two variables (that don't require Mysql). The rest of the script seems to not recognise the variables in `function(data)`.

Answer (score 2):

create a php script that will generate your js and instead of linking your script tag to the .js file link it to the php script that generates the js

PHP

```
<?php
//mysql stuff up here
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
?>
//some js here 
var tag_name = '<?php echo $tag_name ?>';
var client_id = '<?php echo $client_id ?>';
// some more js here
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/test.js.php"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, I was searching for this, but It is not working for me for some reason. I have a select like this there: $sql="SELECT CENA FROM updat WHERE ID='8'";
$cenaa = mysqli_query($con,$sql); and I want to print out that value with js : $(function () {
$('#cena1').html(cena);

});

Answer (score 1):

You can echo out your php variables as JSON and then consume them, but if you're just trying to set your js variables with data from php you might want to simply pass the variables in through a function call. Adding something like this to your php script to activate the Javascript you're trying to use for the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setVariables('<?php echo $tag_name ?>', '<?php echo $client_id ?>');
</script>
```

and then creating that function in your .js file to utilize those values and do what you need.

```
function setVariables(name, id){
    var tag_name = name
    var client_id = id
    //Operations that need these values.
}
```