# Scope issue (javascript)

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am running javascript variables from `Mysql` using `PHP` with `Ajax/JSON`. My original question can be found here: [from mysql to javascript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938787/from-mysql-to-javascript-variable). Basically I now am having an issue with the variables being recognised throughout the remainder of the script. On my last question you see the two variables go from:

```
var tag_name = 'example';
var client_id = '123456789';
```

To now using (Thank you @Richard Rodriguez):

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'call.php',
   dataType: 'json'
}).done(
   function(data){
     var tag_name = data[0];
     var client_id = data[1];
   }
);
```

I believe the issue might just be a `javascript function conflict`? Here is a link to the script I am trying to modify from github: https://raw.github.com/ryancw/instagram-scroll/master/instagram-scroll.js. I hope seeing the original file can help diagnose what is causing the issue? I researched for that the last 2 hours with no luck. Any suggestions or even links to good articles on javascript function conflicts (if that is the issue) will be a great help.

EDIT (Full Code):

```
var tag_name = null;
var client_id = null;
var thumb_dimension = null;
var div_to_add_pics = null;
var include_caption = null;
var include_username = null;
var url = null;

function processData() {
   console.log(tag_name);
   console.log(thumb_dimension);  
    console.log(div_to_add_pics);
    console.log(include_caption);
   console.log(include_username);
   console.log(url);
}

$.ajax({
   url: 'call.php',
   dataType: 'json'
}).done(
   function(data){
     tag_name = data[0];
     client_id = data[1];
     thumb_dimension = 220;
    div_to_add_pics = '#img';
    include_caption = false;
    include_username = false;
    url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'+tag_name+'/media/recent?client_id='+client_id;
     processData();
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is scope not function conflict. The way the variables are declared they are visible in the local scope only, you either need to use them there, or pass them to another function that can use them, or (while polluting the global scope) declare them globally and remove the var keywords in the .done callback

**using them locally**

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'call.php',
   dataType: 'json'
}).done(
   function(data){
     var tag_name = data[0];
     var client_id = data[1];

     var clienttag = client_id+tag_name;
     //blah blah blah
   }
);
```

**passing them to another function**

```
function processData(tag_name,client_id) {
   console.log(tag_name);
   console.log(client_id);  
}

$.ajax({
   url: 'call.php',
   dataType: 'json'
}).done(
   function(data){
     var tag_name = data[0];
     var client_id = data[1];
     processData(tag_name,client_id);
   }
);
```

**declaring globally** (which is the least optimal as it pollutes the global space)

```
var tag_name = null;
var client_id = null;

function processData() {
   console.log(tag_name);
   console.log(client_id);  
}

$.ajax({
   url: 'call.php',
   dataType: 'json'
}).done(
   function(data){
     tag_name = data[0];
     client_id = data[1];
     processData();
   }
);
```

Comment: fair warning that if you do option 3 (global), people won't want to be your friend anymore.  just sayin...

Comment: @Patrick Thanks a lot, that information did help me understand the issue better. Considering I am trying to make it work with the script on github (which is linked), I would want to declare them globally as the variables are used throughout the entire script, in other variables, in `ProcessData(response)` and other functions. Tried using all three methods with no luck.

Comment: if you need them global then the third option will work, if it didnt then you did not copy it correctly. the 2 variables should be declared in the global space (outside any function)

Comment: @PatrickEvans Third option should work, I cannot diagnose why it does not, can you check the github raw file I linked?

Comment: there is a global variable named `url` that builds a url from the two variables, unless you have modified `url` in your ajax `done` callback function then the `loadResults` function which uses the global `url` variable is using a invalid url. that is the only thing i can see, you should edit your question to show how you modified that script so we can see how you modified it.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Added modified code to question. Thank you so much for your time! I hope to be one day at your level man, you're helping me out immensely!

Comment: cant see anything immediately wrong with it, do you get any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: @PatrickEvans Alright, I cleared cache and it got it working. Only issue is I need to scroll to generate the feed otherwise it loads blank.

Comment: the script is setup to only load images when the user scrolls, to do an initial load add a call to `loadNext()` in your `.done` ajax callback function

Comment: @PatrickEvans Man, you're honestly a god. I cannot thank you enough. I will happily paypal you for your if you'd like? Cannot thank you enough.